# How do I execute code on all WFE servers?

Tags: 2007, web-part

I have some code that needs to execute on all WFE servers - does anyone have suggestions on the best way to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a timer job with SPJobLockType.None - that lock type will run on every server.

[Here is a sample by Andrew Connell](http://www.andrewconnell.com/Creating-Custom-SharePoint-Timer-Jobs)

SharePoint internally uses timer jobs for tasks that need to run on all servers (e.g. solution deployment)

Comment: The current setup we have involves a feature that has a webpage with a button - the user clicks this button and then this block of code is supposed to execute on all WFE's but it doens't seem like that happening.  Since I'm not all that familiar with timer jobs do you think the code could be moved into the timer job and then trigger that timer job with a button click?

Comment: Timer jobs based on a user action have some interesting permission issues, as they are intended to be used automatically / from Central Admin. What is it that you are trying to accomplish on the user end that needs to run on all WFEs? There may be a different mechanism. (It would be best to elaborate in your question)

Comment: We are caching some data on the WFE's - the caches only updates every week, but there are times where we would need to force it to update on demand.  The idea behind the feature was to give the user a way to force that cached data to be refreshed.

Comment: Caching your data using another approach may be a better way to go, e.g. create a SharePoint list to store it.

Comment: It would seem using SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase would limit the job running only on the WFE's... http://manomangaldas.blogspot.com/2008/06/sharepoint-job-spjoblocktype-which-one.html

Comment: No. That runs it once per content database, which is not the same as once per WFE. To limit it specifically to WFEs and not App servers, you use the Service parameter - http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2012/06/10/where-is-my-sharepoint-2010-custom-timer-job-running.aspx